# What is the unexpected syntax error in this string? [Related to \\]

Tags: php

I received the following error message:

```
[19-Feb-2017 17:16:36 Asia/Singapore] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$winpath' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp64\www\setting.php on line 3

[19-Feb-2017 17:16:36 Asia/Singapore] PHP Stack trace:

[19-Feb-2017 17:16:36 Asia/Singapore] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp64\www\flush.php:0
```

The following are the content in setting.php:

```
<?php 

$winpath = '\\hdb-ppt\stockpile\barcodes\';

?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be as follows:

```
<?php 

$winpath = '\\hdb-ppt\stockpile\barcodes\\';

?>
```

The last `\` escaped `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this.To escape `\` you have to use `\\`.

```
$winpath = "\\hdb-ppt\\stockpile\\barcodes\\";
echo $winpath;//outputs \hdb-ppt\stockpile\barcodes\
```